# Error being," constructor JLabel.JLabel is not applicable, formal and acutal arguments differ in lenghts"

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Experting extends JFrame{


private JLabel label; 
private JButton nextQuestion;
private JButton yesAnswer;
private JButton noAnswer;

private String array1[] ={ 
" Do you have cold ?", " Do you have headache ?", " Do you feel   enter   enter code here`code here dizzy ?", " Do you have fever ?", 
" Do you feel fatigue ?", " Have you seen mosquitoes in your bedroom recently; You don't sleep in a bed-net ?",
" Have you had malaria before , If yes do you have similar symptoms as before ?",
" Do you stay out at night sometimes",
" Has someone in your house had malaria recently ?"," You have not taken malaria treatment for the past 7 days ?",`
" Do you have chills or sweat much when asleep ?"," Do you vomit or have nausea ?"};

    public Experting(){

        super("Testing Experting");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel(array1);// this constructor

        add(label);
```

the constructor does not work and i can't figure out this constructor does seem to work
when i compile it gives an error as show in the title, can anyone pls help, thanks
Richard.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html

Answer (score 2):

`JLabel's` constructor accepts argument of type `String` and not an **array** of Strings.

Either use one of the strings in your array :

```
label = new JLabel(array1[index]);
```

Or concatenate the strings into one `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass array of Strings to JLabel Constructor. refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) to find what kind of arguments that you can pass, when you initialize a JLabel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a simple String in the arguments for your label?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [official documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)  and  have a look if  you are able to find any constructor that accepts  `array of strings` ,

always refer to official documentation for such problems .